# How to scroll to the bottom when using RecyclerView, PagedListAdater and Room?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

Generally we can use the following code to go to the bottom if all data has been loaded into memory.

`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(YourArraylist.size()-1);`

But when using PagedListAdater and Room, the entity of the last item wasn't loaded at all. So when calling `recyclerView.scrollToPosition`, I can scroll with the scroll bar, but the data doesn't show. On my screen, I saw some words like "ABV.."; and if I scroll up/down manually, these view might be able to show correct.

BTW, I also tried `((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(index,0);`, it doesn't work either.

The associated code is as below,

```
DataSource.Factory<Integer, ContactWithSectionView> dsFactory = contactDao.listAll();

concertList = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(dsFactory, 5)
                .build();

concertList.observe((LifecycleOwner)context,(pagedList) -> {
            this.adapter.submitList(pagedList);
        });
```

```
@Dao
public interface ContactDao {
    @Query("select * from ContactWithSectionView")
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, ContactWithSectionView> listAll();
}
```

I tried to call `concertList.getValue().loadAround(index)` to load data before call `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(int)`, it didn't work either. -- index is the position where I want to move to.

---

Finally, I gave up. didn't use the PagedListAdapter + Room, and load all items to memory in one time.

Comment: If the RecyclerView doesn't load the whole data list and you want to scroll to the bottom with whole data list. You can manually trigger the `load more` action after Adapter fill with whole data list scroll RecyclerView to bottom.

Comment: How to trigger `load more` manually?

Comment: According to your code how do you get new data from `Room` and add it to Adapter

Comment: I just put my code. can you help to check how to do it?  ContactDao.listAll() is to load data from database.

Comment: `ContactDao.listAll()` return a `DataSource.Factory` which define the data source config not a `load` logic.  So where is your `load` data logic like read data from database or request network to get data.

Comment: We use the Paging Library (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging), only need provide a DataSource.Factory, the library will load data from database automatically.

Comment: I have not use `paging` library, but i have read some code of `paging` demo. Most of them using `BoundaryCallback` and implement `onItemAtFrontLoaded` and `onItemAtEndLoaded` to handle scroll top and bottom situation

Comment: BoundaryCallback is called only when has no data (or no more data) ; in my case, only need load data from database, so needn't set `BoundaryCallback `. Thanks @Magic !